# Generate a useful graph from tabular data - 'r' beginner

Tags: r

This is a diagram from a book I'm reading :

[image]

I'm attempting to graph this tabular data using R.

This is what I have so far :

```
a <- c(1000 , 5 , 1050 , 1050 , -2 , 1029 , 1029 , 4 , 1070 , 1070 , -3 , 
1038 , 1038 , 2 , 1059 , 1059 , 4 , 1101)
matrix(a , 3 , 6)
```

This code returns :

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] 1000 1050 1029 1070 1038 1059
[2,]    5   -2    4   -3    2    4
[3,] 1050 1029 1070 1038 1059 1101
```

When I attempt to plot this data using :

```
> plot(matrix(a , 3 , 6))
```

This is the result :

[image]

This graph is not very useful, im new to 'R'. Is there a more interesting graph which can be generated using 'R' ? How can this be amended so that two lines are plotted, with the column 'ETF A' on the 'Y' axis and lines for "Return (% Increase or Decrease), "Balance, End of Year) on 'X' axis ?

Comment: What do you expect your output plot to look like?

Comment: This is not a good question for SO, as it is not specific, vague, and open-ended. You should read some kind of introduction to R, but as a quick nudge in the right direction you can try `plot(data.frame(matrix(a , 6 , 3, byrow=TRUE, dimnames=list(NULL, c("ETF_A", "Return", "Balance")))))`

Comment: @Nathan G ive updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
a <- c(1000 , 5 , 1050 , 1050 , -2 , 1029 , 1029 , 4 , 1070 , 1070 , -3 , 
     1038 , 1038 , 2 , 1059 , 1059 , 4 , 1101)
x <- matrix(a , 3 , 6)

# make it a data.frame :)
z <- data.frame(b = c(x[1, ], x[3, ]), year = c(rep(0, 6), rep(1, 6)))

# make a mysterious plot
plot(z[, 2], z[, 1]) + segments(x0=z[1:6, 2], y0=z[1:6, 1], x1=z[7:12, 2], y1=z[7:12, 1])
```

[image]

Edits can be made to change the x and y labs, title, etc.  Type ?par into the console to see many, many options.  The slope relates very closely to your percentage increase/decrease. :)